# Custom page show blog posts on tag

Tags: php, wordpress, post, tags, singlepage

Since I am not so great programming in PHP I wanted to ask my question here, hopefully you guys can help me out.

I'm building a WordPress website, this website has a custom page template like `custom-single.php`.

On that custom template I want to show posts filtered on a tag. And the tag is coming from a Angular value like so `{{ctrl.name.tagname}}` and yes ofcourse I've made a tag as well in WordPress.

The code must show max 5 posts (fully with title and ofcourse the content), after the posts it must show max 5 items which are older then 5 posts before, but then only with title using a bullet-list.

Comment: Better to show what did you try, what errors or incorrect results you've got, so the question would be how to fix it. Currently it looks like let's someone do my work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/

When you install and activate this plugin called Display Posts Shortcode, you will add the feature that enables you to create text lists.

If we want to list our articles about a label, we can use a shortcode like [display-posts tag = ”tag_name”].

Number of posts to be displayed on one page (eg 20): posts_per_page = ”20 ″

I hope it will be the answer

Comment: Thank you this is worth the answer instead of all down votes, thank you for this. The only thing I need to change is the template styling for this,

Answer (score 1):

1. If your aim is not to learn php but only to solve your problem in your wordpress related project; you can support your question with visuals.
2. If you say I don't want to deal with the problem, you can get support from any freelance software developer at an affordable price. Sometimes you will be happier soon with this method.

Comment: Thank you for that, but ofcourse it would not answer my question.. Will try to update my question soon in the hope someone can help me with.